# How to apply filter for output of aggregation framework of Mongo Db?

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

I'm trying to apply condition for the output of the aggregation of Mongo Db but still do not figure out the idea. Here are my sample documents:

```
{
 'id':1,
 'customerReviews':[5,7,8],
 'expertReviews':[9,8,9]
},
{
 'id':1,
 'customerReview':[6,7,7],
 'expertReview':[4,8,9]
}
```

So if I have a requirement like find all documents which has min(customer_review) > 5 -> only the second document is correct.

Here is my initial point which get the min(customerReview) of documents:

```
db.getCollection('subscriber').aggregate([
{$unwind:"$customerReviews"},
{"$group":{
   "_id":"$_id",
   "min_customer_review":{"$min":"$customerReviews"}}}
]);
```

which produces:

```
{
  "_id" : ObjectId("58ab1d6892bf3194a9719883"),
  "min_customer_review" : 5
},
{
  "_id" : ObjectId("58ab1d6892bf3194a9719883"),
  "min_customer_review" : 6
}
```

So how to continue apply filter for aggregation output to get all documents which has min_customer_review > 5?

One more question, is it able to apply second aggregation, like "get all movies which has min_customer_review > 5 or average_expert_reviews > 6" ?

Thank u all

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `$redact`.

`$redact` to go through document and perform `$$KEEP` and `$$PRUNE` on the query criteria.

```
db.subscriber.aggregate(
    [{
        $redact: {
            $cond: {
                if: {
                    $gt: [{
                        $min: "$customerReviews"
                    }, 5]
                },
                then: "$$KEEP",
                else: "$$PRUNE"
            }
        }
    }]
);
```

You can wrap more conditions in `$or` operator.

Replace the value in `if` block with

```
{ $or:[{$gt: [{ $min: "$customerReviews"}, 5 ] }, {$gt: [{ $avg: "$expertReviews"}, 6 ] } ]}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, so how to perform condition on every elements of the list like "at lease 1 expert review > 8". I try: { $or:[{$gt: [{ $min: "$customerReviews"}, 5 ] }, {expertReviews:{$elemMatch:{$gt:8}}} ]} but it returned Unrecognized expression $elemMatch - InvalidPipelineOperator. And final question: all these kinds of query can be done using BasicDbObject for Java, right?

Comment: You are welcome. All operations are supported in java driver. `$elemmatch` only works in `$match`stage. I cant think  of any similar operator in aggregation pipeline.